# Python list extension and variable assignment

Tags: python, list, variable-assignment, extend

I tried to extend a list and was puzzled by having the result return with the value None. What I tried was this:

```
>>> a = [1,2]  
>>> b = [3,4]  
>>> a = a.extend(b)  
>>> print a  

None
```

I finally realized that the problem was the redundant assignment to 'a' at the end. So this works:

```
>>> a = [1,2]  
>>> b = [3,4]  
>>> a.extend(b)  
>>> print a  

[1,2,3,4]
```

What I don't understand is *why* the first version didn't work. The assignment to 'a' was redundant, but why did it break the operation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because, as you noticed, the return value of `extend` is `None`. This is common in the Python standard library; destructive operations return `None`, i.e. no value, so you won't be tempted to use them as if they were pure functions. Read [Guido's explanation](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-October/038855.html) of this design choice.

E.g., the `sort` method on lists returns `None` as well, while the non-destructive `sorted` function returns a value.

Answer (score 4):

Because all the in-place functions return `None`, to emphasize the fact that they're mutating their argument. Otherwise, you might assign the return value to something, not realising that the argument had also changed.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Your answer was correct too, of course. I just had to pick one to accept!

Answer (score 0):

Simply .extend() returns none

If u want you can join them as such;

a= a+b